# Spring Tests Do Not Store Data in Database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao, spring-test

I am running some tests for a game with Spring but for some reason the data in the sql files is not being persisted to the database. Here is my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {HibernateConfigTest.class})
@Transactional
@Sql(scripts = {"api_routes.sql",
                "profile.sql",
                "status.sql",
                "user.sql",
                "game_token.sql",
                "game.sql",
                "message.sql"},
    executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
@Sql(scripts = "delete_data.sql", 
    executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
public class GameDaoTest {
    @Autowired
    private GameDao gameDao;

    @Test
    public void testGetGamesByTokenId() {
        assertEquals(36, gameDao.getGamesByTokenId(null).size());
    }
}
```

When I run the test, the test succeeds. When I go to look at the database, however, during the test none of the data is in there. It appears like Spring is running an in memory database without my knowledge.

Is there anyway to ensure that the data is being persisted to the database?

Comment: I am far from from knowledgeable about the Spring platform, but I wonder about `@Sql(scripts = "delete_data.sql", 
    executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)`

Comment: What makes you wonder about that? The test passes just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = ISOLATED)` to the `@SQL` annotation for the sql to be run in a separate transaction.

Example:

```
@Sql(
    scripts = "...",
    config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = ISOLATED),
    executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD
)
```

[Relevant Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-executing-sql-declaratively)

Comment: The problem with this is that the data isn't deleted after the test is finished.

Comment: So that works, but I need to add that config statement to the deleting sql annotation as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can set you transaction to not roll back using

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
```